# Memory Corruption C++

Tags: c++

After some criticism regarding this post I have decided to try another solution to test my issue.

I purpose of the code below was to save user input into an array and then output it when user types in `exit`. I am relatively new to C++ which means that I am aware that this is a code issue.

The constraints for this code are to not use STL or strings.

I have attached the code below which does not give the desired output, instead it prints out "exit" the number of times equal to the number of items stored in the array.

```
#include <iostream>

char * textArr[1000];
int lineCount = 0;

void saveText(char * text) {
    textArr[lineCount] = new char(1000);
    strcpy(textArr[lineCount], text);
}


int main()
{
    char * line = new char(1000);

    while (lineCount < 1000) {
        std::cin.getline(line , 1000);

        if (strcmp(line, "exit") == 0) {
            break;
        }

        saveText(line);
        lineCount++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++) {
        std::cout << textArr[i] << std::endl;
    }

    delete(textArr);
    delete(line);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Create a [mcve]. Also, why do you think that the map key was corrupted? I admit I haven't used VS debugger; does it really have a feature that tells which objects in memory are corrupted?

Comment: Compile your program with debugging symbols and run it with valgrind. `valgrind ./yourprogram`. This should be able to find where you are getting memory corrupted. I think by the time you are reading `instr`, it's already corrupted.

Comment: As a wild guess, (I'm not sure because I'm not familiar with `std::regex`) the second parameter to `std::regex_match` takes a `const&`, but it's possible that it expects the `std::regex` to not be a temporary. What if you defined the regex as a variable instead of inline?

Comment: @Justin It's perfectly fine to pass a temporary to a function that has a `const&` parameter.

Comment: @zett42 I know, my point is that it's possible that `std::regex_match` expects it to not be a temporary (uses it after the temporary would be destroyed). Idk if this even matters, but that's a "wild guess" for you

Comment: @user2079303 I am submitting as much information as I can in hopes that this might be a known issue that I cannot find using Google. For the memory bit, please refer to the image I have posted a link to, the map key is turned from "b" to a weird set of characters.

Comment: @Justin It does not seem to work with the `std::regex` being declared as a separate variable. It just results in the key being changed twice. If I comment out this piece of code, everything works fine.

Comment: @Justin At least [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match) doesn't state anything about that.

Comment: @Justin functions can not use their arguments after the function has returned. A temporary argument of a function is not destroyed until the function has returned.

Comment: @OskarAugustyn, valgrind use case is exactly this. Just install valgrind, run your program with it and let it find the problem for you.

Comment: @partycode I have looked at valgrind but from what I can see it is Linux only (I am currently using Windows). I have looked at alternatives and found Dr. Memory (http://stackoverflow.com/a/6580332) however it experiences an internal crash when I drag my executable to it.

Comment: @user2079303 I have updated the question with a more concise, reproducible example.

Comment: You are using a single buffer for line, so you are storing that buffer's pointer in every location of your array (and overwriting the same buffer's contents in your read loop, so you end up with an array of elements all pointing to the same single buffer that contains your last line).  You need to allocate memory for each line in the loop (and you should consider freeing that memory at the end of your program)

Comment: @Joe, I have modified the saveText function to use strcpy however the program now crashes during the `textArr[lineCount] = new char(1000)` line due to "A heap has been corrupted"

Comment: Did you maybe mean `new char[1000]`?

Comment: Don't delete textArr, since you didn't allocate it with new.